# The user aborted a request - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, abort

I got an issue on my javascript program
my project separate to 2 files:

1. backend -> NodeJS (work fine I check the routes using POSTMAN and I got the Data.
2. frontend -> I do get data from backend but I got an issue when I want to display all
   users (that located in DB).

on the frontend I got 2 files that got the issue:
my hook -> http-hook.js:

```
  import { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
  export const useHttpClient = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const actieveHttpRequests = useRef([]); //store data accross re render cycle (if the user change page before we finish the proccess with the DB)
  //we use useRef and not useState because we dont wont to update the UI.

  //when the component that use this hook re render
  //useCallback make sure that there are no infinity loops when ever the component is rerender
  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (url, method = "GET", body = null, headers = {}) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const httpAbortCtrl = new AbortController(); //API Supported in modern browser
      //current properties -> access to the data in useRef
      actieveHttpRequests.current.push(httpAbortCtrl);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method, //method: method
          body,
          headers,
          signal: httpAbortCtrl.signal, //link the AbortController to this request
        });
        const responseData = await response.json();
        actieveHttpRequests.current = actieveHttpRequests.current.filter(
          (reqCtrl) => reqCtrl !== httpAbortCtrl
        ); //filter all the old request controller
        if (!response.ok) {
          //the response.ok will be true if the status code is 200
          // not ok is mean we got 400 or 500
          throw new Error(responseData.message); //trigger the catch block
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(responseData);
        return responseData;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("there is the error: " + err);
        setError(err.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
        throw err;
      }
    },
    [] //no specific dependecie so we add an empty array
  );

  const clearError = () => {
    setError(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //when we return a function in this first function than the return function is excecuted as a clean function
    //before the next time use effect runs again or also when the component that uses useEffect unmounts
    return () => {
      actieveHttpRequests.current.forEach((abortCtrl) => abortCtrl.abort());
    };
  }, []);

  return { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError }; //isLoading:isLoading , error:error
};
```

by using this hook I can send request to the backend and get my results.

**You can Note that I put 2 line of code of console.log so on the image you can see that I do got the error, but than I got the results from the DataBase**

on the other file UserList.js (here I wish to display my users, but the error in only on the useEffect function, I haven't try to display the data on the DataGrid, , I just try at first to get the DATA from the backend):

**

- UserList.js:

**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./userList.css";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { DeleteOutline } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { userRows } from "../../dummyData";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ErrorModal from "../../shared/components/UIElements/ErrorModal";
import LoadingSpinner from "../../shared/components/UIElements/LoadingSpinner";
import { useHttpClient } from "../../shared/hooks/http-hook";

const UserList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(userRows);
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const [loadedUsers, setLoadedUsers] = useState();

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        //with fetch, the default request type is GET request
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "/users"
        );
        setLoadedUsers(responseData.users); //users propeties is the given value from the backend (user-controllers.js on getUsers())
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, [sendRequest]);

  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    {
      field: "user",
      headerName: "Username",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <div className="userListUser">
            <img className="userListImg" src={params.row.avatar} alt="" />
            {params.row.username}
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    { field: "email", headerName: "Email", width: 200 },
    { field: "status", headerName: "status", width: 120 },
    { field: "transaction", headerName: "Transaction Volume", width: 160 },
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Link to={"/users/" + params.row.id}>
              <button className="userListEdit">Edit</button>
            </Link>
            <DeleteOutline
              className="userListDelete"
              onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)}
            />
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
      {isLoading && (
        <div className="center">
          <LoadingSpinner />
        </div>
      )}
      {/* we need to render loadedUsers only if not empty*/}
      {!isLoading && loadedUsers && (
        <div className="userList">
          <span className="Title">User List</span>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "80%" }}>
            <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              <DataGrid
                disableSelectionOnClick
                rows={data}
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={5}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                checkboxSelection
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

to remind, on http-hoolk I put those 2 line of code:
on the error:

```
console.log("there is the error: " + err);
```

on the results:

```
 console.log(responseData);
```

The Image of the error on the web tools:
[image]

Comment: who said using hook for making a simple http request was good idea, code has become mess you really need to refactor it.

Comment: @bogdanoff my guide from Udemy done it XD

Answer (score 2):

I got no idea why but on my index.js I had this code:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

All I had to do is remove the React.StrictMode and the error remove!

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

Comment: thats bad practice see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: @bogdanoff what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

Effects firing twice is an expected behavior in development mode of React 18 with StrictMode enabled.

[More info.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502#issuecomment-1118754581)